# Cakephp, JsHelper call a javascript function on "update"?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp

I have a js helper method like this:

```
$this->Js->get('#colorRB' . $key)->event('change', $this->Js->request(array(
            'controller' => 'designer',
            'action' => 'setParameters', $colorHex['id'], $colorHex['hex_code'], $cNr, False
                ), array(
            'update' => '#testDiv',
            'async' => true,
            'method' => 'post',
            'dataExpression' => true
        ))
);
```

Is it possible to call a javascript method -> *reloadJs()* when "update" occurs? Or how to rebuild the method to do this? i am only interested in calling the action"setParameters", not in anything it returns. After that i need the javascript to be called, this needs to be done after becous ut depends on what the action does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run JavaScript in the callbacks, as defined in the [`request()`](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/js-base-engine-helper#method-JsBaseEngineHelperrequest) method. The 'update' key is just a convenient way of automatically updating a div, it does nothing more. To run JS after the request succeeds, for example:

```
$this->Js->get('#colorRB' . $key)->event('change', $this->Js->request(array(
    'controller' => 'designer',
    'action' => 'setParameters', $colorHex['id'], $colorHex['hex_code'], $cNr, False
        ), array(
    'success' => 'reloadJs()',
    'async' => true,
    'method' => 'post',
    'dataExpression' => true
))
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I got it working by _'error' => 'reloadJs()',_ how do you return a sucess from the action? It seems like it returns error by default?

Comment: It should only return error if jQuery does. Check the source it produces to make sure that FormHelper is putting it in the correct callback.

Comment: So its not dependent on any return from the called action? In the correct callback? The action call does what its supposed to do if that what you mean?

Comment: Those are the jQuery response callbacks. If the request succeeds, it will call the success callback. If it fails (like a 404 or 500) jQuery calls the error callback.